# Digital Certificates, exhaustive set of their uses and references

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, hash

I am a newbie of sorts as far as particulars of security is concerned.can somebody list all the possible uses of a digital certificate? it is used in SSL, signing and what else? Also is there a good reference book or article to understand certificates in its entirety?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit like asking for an exhaustive list of the uses of paper.

In a broad sense, certificates do one thing: linking a public key to a name.

That public key can belong to a signing algorithm, or a key exchange algorithm, or an encryption algorithm. So literally any kind of public-key cryptography can be put into a certificate.

So in a broad sense, your question reduces to: *"can somebody list all the possible uses of cryptography?"*.

I would start with a general-purpose cryptography text book, paying special attention to the chapters on public key crypto.